# Blender Preferences > System > Memory & Limits = RAM or VRAM?

Tags: rendering, customization, memory-management

I'm trying to optimize my Blender 3.0 under Windows 11 and I occasionally get a render error stating that I've run out of "GPU Memory." **Blender Preferences > System** offers various memory settings, but they don't specify whether they're referring to system RAM (I have 64GB) or VRAM (8GB). I can't find info on what sort of memory these options address. RAM? VRAM? or both? Thanks.

Operating system: Windows-10-10.0.22000-SP0 64 Bits
Graphics card: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Ti/PCIe/SSE2 NVIDIA Corporation 4.5.0 NVIDIA 511.23

Comment: System RAM, not VRAM

Comment: "out of GPU memory" usually means that your scene does not fit onto your graphics card anymore and you'd have to find a way reducing memory usage. One easy way is to close everything else and try rendering from the command line. If that does not help, you'd have to optimize your scene (textures, polygons etc.) or render using your CPU (unfortunately).